# how to call a blade file dynamically in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm calling a blade that way:

```
<a href="{{ asset('views/quem-somos.blade.php') }}" class="dropdown-toggle" 
   data-toggle="dropdown">Quem somos</a>
```

but is returning that in the file does not exist, how would the correct way of calling in href be?

Comment: Views are not in the public folder so you cant create a link to it

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling the view files like that, create a url in the routes.php/web.php depending on your laravel version and have the url point to the blade instead.

```
Route::get("/quem-somos", function() {
  return view("quem-somos");
});
```

And in the current file, change the link to

```
<a href="/quem-somos" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Quem somos</a>
```

Comment: Maybe give the route a name, and use href="{{ route('name') }}. Prettier way to have all routes be named routes, in my opinion. It saves you the trouble of replacing all occurrences if you ever decide to change the url of a route. You can still refer to it by name, and it'll be magically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@include('quem-somos')` wherever you're wanting the blade to be inserted.